# TypeError: string indices must be integers in a function

Tags: python, typeerror

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
def divideEnTam(cadena, num):
  lista=[]
  for x in range (0, len(cadena)//num):
    lista.append(cadena[(x-num), x])
  print (lista)

divideEnTam("Paracaidas", 2)
```

I would like to see the following:

```
["Pa", "ra", "ca", "id", "as"]
```

However instead I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so17405138.py", line 7, in <module>
    divideEnTam("Paracaidas", 2)
  File "so17405138.py", line 4, in divideEnTam
    lista.append(cadena[(x-num), x])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `cadena[(x-num), x]` supposed to do?

Comment: Select the characters from every certain number, so with the function divideEnTam("Paracaidas", 2) should print ["Pa", "ra", "ca", "id", "as"]

Comment: You can stride by 2s and then slice in 2s: `[s[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(s), 2)]`.

Answer (score 1):

String slicing is done with a `:`, not a `,`.

Try the following:

```
def divideEnTam(cadena, num):
  lista=[]
  for x in range (0, len(cadena)//num):
    lista.append(cadena[(x-num):x])  # Fixed slicing
  print (lista)

divideEnTam("Paracaidas", 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it in a simple way

```
def divideEnTam(cadena, num):
     return [cadena[i:i+num] for i in range(0, len(cadena), num)]

divideEnTam("Paracaidas", 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not paying attention to what python is telling you.

When you run your program, you get a traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so17405138.py", line 7, in <module>
    divideEnTam("Paracaidas", 2)
  File "so17405138.py", line 4, in divideEnTam
    lista.append(cadena[(x-num), x])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

The last line in the traceback tells you what the problem is, namely that string indices must be integers. Then as you read upwards you'll see that the problem is on line 4:

```
lista.append(cadena[(x-num), x])
```

If you work your way through the expression, you might try something like this first:

```
>>> cadena = "Paracaidas"
>>> cadena[(4-3), 4]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

that would tell you that there's something wrong with what's inside the `[]`. You know that both the result of 4-3 and 4 are integers, so the next thing that you can try is check what that expression is:

```
>>> x = (4-3), 4
>>> print(type(x), repr(x))
<class 'tuple'> (1, 4)
```

Ah hah! So it turns out that `(4-3), 4` is a *tuple*. If you read more [about tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) you'll see that they're actually not defined by *parenthesis* but by *commas*. What you probably wanted was a *slice*, which you get by replacing `,` with `:`.

However, if you try that:

```
def divideEnTam(cadena, num):
  lista=[]
  for x in range (0, len(cadena)//num):
    lista.append(cadena[(x-num): x])
  print (lista)

divideEnTam("Paracaidas", 2)
```

You'll see that you've got something wrong:

```
['', '', 'Pa', 'ar', 'ra']
```

If you think about it for a moment, and adjust your statement to this:

```
for x in range (0, len(cadena)//num):
    print(x-num, x)
```

You'll see this output:

```
-2 0
-1 1
0 2
1 3
2 4
```

If you notice this starts out at `-2`. It's not the output that you're really looking for. You want something more like this:

```
0 2
2 4
4 6
6 8
8 10
```

Do you know how to do *that* with a [range](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#func-range)?